# Any step-by-step introductions of tensors with practical examples out there?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, tensors, education

*[tragic] Preface:*

My goal is simple — as part of studying linear algebra I want to get a feel of what tensors are, how to use them and generally get comfortable at using that kind of language. However, I feel that nothing helps me to understand any subject better than carefully written primitive examples.

Basically all the stuff one can find in undergrad linear algebra (matrix operations, changes of basis, permuations, diagonalization, eigenvalues\eigenvectors, dual spaces etc.) won't really click for me until I do at least a dozen of exercises and cast away the initial confusion.

That brings me to the point — I can't find any books, articles, guides, videos of that sort when it comes to tensors. Yes, I've checked many wonderful posts here. Yes, I've checked youtube playlists for that. Yes, I've checked smth around 20-30 books that are targeted at 'absolute beginners'. No, I haven't found anything that would be remotely useful.

Most often those sources indeed start simple, carrying out, say, vector addition or dot product with great clarity. Sadly, when they reach more advanced topics the clarity fades away and I find myself left alone with highly abstract math notation I can work with but struggle to find intuitive.

**Main question:**

At this point I don't think there's much hope, but still, maybe anyone here knows anything of that type of approach? I get it that writing 'cubes of numbers' etc. isn't very convenient and high dimensional visualization instantly get messy, I'll deal with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf.

Comment: thanks for suggestion! but that article displays the same trend — starting with few basic examples it quickly proceeds to purely abstract definitions with no nothing to grab to. 

the closest stuff to what I'm looking for would be some of the following approaches:
https://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/tensors-tensors-tensors
https://www.math3ma.com/blog/the-tensor-product-demystified